# deny direct access but allow fopen

Tags: php, .htaccess, fopen

i am trying to read txt file from my webhost using

```
echo file_get_contents("http://domain/text.txt");
```

Or

```
$fh =  fopen("http://domain/text.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fh)) {
   $line = fgets($fh);
   echo $line;
}
```

but i wanted to protect this text file from direct access

using .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

but i couldnt read text file anymore after denied direct access :(

also i dont want use all from ip

so i am asking if there any solution to read the text file with php and deny direct access to the file

Thank You

Comment: If you deny HTTP, then this won't work.  Is the file on the same host as the PHP script?  If so, just open the local file by it's path.

Comment: no it isnt on same host,

Comment: To the remote server, there's no difference from your fopen with a URL and a user connecting from a browser.  You could secure the remote file behind some kind of authentication and use that in your script.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to put the files you want kept to yourself outside of the web root directory. This works because the web server follows local file system privileges, not its own privileges.

Comment: but i want to read it with php because i will use it for another script